# Add arbitrary metadata to a FormControl

Tags: angular, angular-forms

Is there a way to add arbitrary metadata to a `FormControl` in Angular2+, when declaring the form model?

Something like:

```js
// In this fake example, {foo: 'bar'} is the metadata
const ctrl = new FormControl('some value', validator, asyncValidator, {foo: 'bar'});
```

I'd like to use this metadata to store the error messages for a specific control.

Note: I can store the error messages in a separate variable, but each of my fields is displayed with a custom component which only receives one @Input: the instance of the FormControl. I'd like to avoid declaring a second input to pass the error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a validator that also returns a message.

Example:

```
static requiredValidator(message: string): ValidatorFn {

        return (control: FormControl): { [id: string]: string | IValidatorMessages } => {

            return (control && control.value && control.value.trim().length) ? undefined : { required: {
                message: message,
                valid: false
            } };
        };
    }
```

You can the use it like this:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', Utilities.requiredValidator('Message')]
    });
```

Then somewhere in your template:

```
{{ form.get('email').errors?.required?.message }}
```